# Live replacement, while viewing log using LESS

Tags: sed, grep, logs, less

It's very convenient to monitor logs using *less* command - you see what is going with your system as it happening. The bad thing is that my logs are optimized for *grep* tool: each atomic action is always printed in a single line (I can easily lookup for actions performed by certain user then).

Still, actions contain incoming messages, which are more user-friendly if being printed multiline. If I want to filter log "offline", it's easy:

```
cat ./log/system.log | tail -50 | tr '\\n' '\n'
```

Can I do those replacements "online"? What I mean is that replacements are done as new text being appended to log and shown to the screen like *less + G*.

Comment: Note that `tr '\\n' '\n'` would transliterate both backslash and n characters to a newline one with haft `tr` implementations, and backslashes only in the other half. That is _not_ substituting `\n` with a newline character.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried replacing `tail -50` with `tail -f` ?

```
tail -fn50 ./log/system.log | sed 's/\\n/\
/g'
```

Comment: tail -F rather than -f, so that the named file is watched. Otherwise things will grind to a halt if the file is archived (i.e. logrotate etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You can if you drop the redundant `cat` command.

```
tail -f ./log/system.log | tr '\\n' '\n'
```

or putting a filter in there:

```
tail -f ./log/system.log | grep [whatever] | tr '\\n' '\n'
```

Comment: `grep` usually needs the `--line-buffered` parameter when taking a stream as input.